# AppImage Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: appimage, 23.04

Yesterday I was on Ubuntu 22.10. My email client [an AppImage] worked just fine.

Today I'm on 23.04 and the email client will not open. I've re-downloaded the Appimage and nothing.

Question: Are AppImages borked in 23.04?

If yes, is there a "how to roll back" process listed somewhere?

Comment: Could you include which email application you use? This would be helpful for others to troubleshoot.

Comment: The email client is Tutanota. I have used to on Ubuntu for 2+ years. Today I updated from 2210 to 2304 Ubuntu and now Tuta' will not open. Yes it is executable, as I have used for ages and no I've not downloaded anything extra as I've not needed to use anything "extra" before.
As for "terminal output" what and how do I need to add here ?

Comment: Please check if you have on your system with Ubuntu 23.04 the package **libfuse2** installed. Without this package, AppImages won't run. The package is not installed as a standard since 22.04, but it is still in the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: try running/installing the image with https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher

Comment: Hi @noisefloor...... Sorted. libfuse2 re-installed and now Tuta' is working just fine. 
Will close etc. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appimage not working in Ubuntu 23.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465797/appimage-not-working-in-ubuntu-23-04)

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. You just need to install **`libfuse2`** using this command:

`sudo apt install libfuse2`

This is because the new version of Ubuntu has been moved to the latest version **`libfuse3`**.

You can refer to this [link](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2023/04/appimages-libfuse2-ubuntu-23-04) for reference.