# Appimage not working in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: appimage, 23.04

Having a problem with Appimage programs not opening when double clicking.They do not respond or attempt to open, same as right clicking and selecting "run".
Have installed the Fuse 2 library, and enabled the checkbox for execute in permissions.
Is there anything else that needs to be done to enable this to work in the latest Ubuntu 23.04?

Comment: I use appimagelauncher to make it easy to associate an app with an app file. https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher

Answer (score 1):

Just install version 2, for me it will help

```
sudo apt install libfuse2
```